# how fwrite() works in c files?

Tags: c, file, c99

fwrite() is used to write structure to the file in c,
suppose we have following structure:

```
struct student{
int rollno;
char name[20],grade;
float total;
};
```

- does it write full `sizeof(struct tudent)`bytes to the file every time we write it with `fwrite()`?
- if so then does it write `name` with 20 bytes of storage on the file even if you have only stored few characters in the `name`?
- if that is the case then can we modify the the written record using `fread()` with other functions such as `fputs() fputc() putw()`,
  but these function doesnt seem to modify the record correctly?

  ```
  #include<stdio.h>
  #include<stdlib.h>
  struct student{
      int rollno;
      char name[20],grade;
      float total;
  };
  void display(struct student s2  ){
      printf("Name: %s\nRoll Number: %d\nTotal markes: %f\nGrade: %c",s2.name,s2.rollno,s2.total,s2.grade);
  }
  int main(){
      struct student s1,s2;
      FILE *fp;
      int choice;
      fp=fopen("file.txt","r+");
      if(!fp){
          printf("\nerror in opening file.txt");
          exit(1);
      }
      printf("Enter student detail:-\nEnter name: ");
      scanf("%s",s1.name);
      printf("Enter rollno: ");
      scanf("%d",&s1.rollno);
      printf("Enter the total marks: ");
      scanf("%f",&s1.total);
      printf("Enter the grade: ");
      scanf(" %c",&s1.grade);
      fwrite(&s1,sizeof(s1),1,fp);
      fseek(fp,0,SEEK_SET);
      fread(&s2,sizeof(s2),1,fp);
      display(s2);
      printf("\nModify student record");
      while(1){
          printf("\n1: modify name\n2: modify rollno\n3: Exit\nchoice: ");
          scanf("%d",&choice);
          switch(choice){
              case 1: printf("\nEnter  name: ");
                      scanf("%s",s1.name);
                      fseek(fp,0,SEEK_SET);
                      fputs(s1.name,fp);
                      fseek(fp,0,SEEK_SET);
                      fread(&s2,sizeof(s2),1,fp);
                      display(s2);
                      break;
              case 2: printf("\nEnter rollno");
                      scanf("%d",&s1.rollno);
                      fseek(fp,sizeof(s1.name),SEEK_SET);
                      putw(s1.rollno,fp);
                      fseek(fp,0,SEEK_SET);
                      fread(&s2,sizeof(s2),1,fp);
                      display(s2);
              default:fclose(fp);
                      return 0;
          }
      }
      return 0;
  }
  ```

Comment: The key here is the size of each member of the struct is fully known. So yes, `fwrite`  using `sizeof (struct student)` will write the whole struct -- allowing you to `fwrite` and `fread` an array of them -- but there is a catch. The padding included in the `sizeof (struct student)` can and will differ from compiler to compiler. Meaning while you can compile `fwrite` and `fread` on one box just fine, there is no guarantee you can take the file written, recompile the code on another machine and expect to read the same data back in. For that you *serialize* the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fwrite` is a C function and deals with structures the way other functions do, without doing any special treatment (unless requested). It takes that struct as a binary object, and writes as many bytes as you want of it.

> does it write full `sizeof(struct tudent)`bytes to the file every time we write it with `fwrite()`?

It writes the size you ask `fwrite` to write, so if it's `sizeof(structX)` it writes that size. If you do the same `fwrite` twice, it will be written twice.

> if so then does it write `name` with 20 bytes of storage on the file even if you have only stored few characters in the `name`?

`name` is declared as `char[20]` which takes 20 bytes. So yes that part takes 20 bytes on disk (even if the "string" contains "only" 3 characters (i.e. a `'\0'` is at the 4th position), all 20 bytes are written).

> if that is the case then can we modify the the written record using `fread()` with other functions such as `fputs() fputc() putw()`,
>   but these function doesnt seem to modify the record correctly?

`putw` writes a *word* to the stream, meaning an `int` as it is (a binary word, not its string representation), but better use `fwrite` as recommended in the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/putw). `fputc` writes a unique character. `fputs` writes a null-terminated string, unlike `fwrite` which writes the number of characters you require regardless if a zero-byte is hidden somewhere in it.

Answer (score 2):

All that fwrite is able to see is the struct in memory. It does not know the name of the fields, their offsets, or any related info. All it can do is essentially write your memory directly into a file. So, it will write all 20 bytes of your string, along with the rest of your struct.

If you want it to write things in a human-readable form, you must write a function that knows about each field and formats them.

This is because C does not possess something called "reflection", which allows the program to store and utilize information such as the name or type of a variable or field, and use that information at runtime. There are other languages, like golang, that are able to do such things.